# Granting Permissions for Facebook Test Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a bunch of users using Facebook's UI:  (my app) -> Roles -> Test Users  Currently my app is in dev mode so no one can see it.

My question:  How do I have these test users to grant permission to write on their facebook wall?

Comment: Just like any user. You login as them and go to your app which popup the login dialog that asks for permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WizKid is right, you can create up to 2000 test users that have full permission tokens granted for your app's use. Your test users will log in and accept permissions like any other user. You can follow the instructions here: [Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by a HTTP POST method :

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/appid/accounts/test-users?permissions=fullpermissions&access_token=accesstoken;
```

where accesstoken is access_token which you can get from Facebook Graph API explorer by clicking "get APP token".
"fullpermissions" secifies all permissions:
"public_profile,user_friends,email,user_about_me,user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_events,user_games_activity,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,user_managed_groups,user_photos,user_posts,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,read_custom_friendlists,read_insights,read_audience_network_insights,read_page_mailboxes,manage_pages,publish_pages,publish_actions,rsvp_event,pages_show_list,pages_manage_cta,pages_manage_leads,ads_read,ads_management";

You can automate this procedure by writing a script or using existing module (like [fb-zombie](https://github.com/gepolv/fb-zombie) if you are a node/javascript fan).